# Spring boot unique id for every transaction

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have the following use case -

1. The user fills up a form.
2. The spring boot backend code calls multiples services before pushing the user data to the database.
3. The database takes more than 10 secs to commit the details

Since the whole process takes time, I want to return a transaction id to the user immediately after he fills up the form. The user can check the status later using the same transaction Id.

Does spring boot provide any feature to achieve this?

Comment: Make it a async request. The moment your API will get request it will give a transaction Id ( you can use any logic here). Then just map this transaction id with the User data in the end. Or make another table which will show the current status of the API request user has made. Update the status every time when you call the any other request.

Comment: or you can using UUID to generate a transaction Id at the time user goto that form, if he submit the form, that value can be used for real transaction Id, if he does not, just forget that value.